# Difference between article, tutorial, how-to, course, track

Tags: differences, meaning-in-context

I find these words(keywords) article, tutorial, how-to, course, track...etc some what same but CS people always use them (even my tutor) in different ways..

Don't assume this is about the programming context, I am asking this in any context possible or applicable but most of these words are used in coding sites like code.org I really think of how these words make difference..

Comment: Who are 'CS people'? Does it stand for computer science? Also, have you tried checking a dictionary? You're likely to get more specific, helpful answers if you clarify what it is you find ambiguous between the definitions of these words.

Comment: By the special terms you employ and the ways you employ them, it sounds like you are a student at a college or university. Every such academic culture has its own way of talking about academic matters, and what a word means depends entirely on the location where it's spoken and the system employed there. And you might give some thought to the idea that the rest of the world is probly not composed of students at schools just like yours, so you shouldn't expect their terminology to be much like yours.

Comment: @568ml CS for Computer science only... and I a EC-electronics&coms student.. I found this post just now while searching for this post....;)   [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48388/differences-between-tutorial-guide-and-how-to).

Answer (score 3):

"Article" is a pretty broad term for any grouping of text that provides factual information, usually written in a style that is for general public consumption. The archetypal example is an article in a magazine or a newspaper.

"Tutorial" is a collection of information for pedagogical/teaching purposes. It is derived from "tutor", usually a one-on-one teacher. So it is writing, or video, or whatever media, that teaches in a manner similar to a tutor.

"How To" is kind of like a tutorial, but the word is slightly less formal. There is a tendency in unix/linux/computer science to use it as one word, often as a filename: HOWTO. For that reason, I tend to think of it as a more computer-science-y term, as opposed to "tutorial" which is more generic.

A "course" usually implies a series of lessons, most often in an institutional context (i.e., at a school or university).

A "track" is typically a set of courses, often held together by a certification or degree received at the end.