# A term for a "visual guide", "example guide", tutorial without words, follow by my example to get the results

Tags: synonyms

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/48400/193880

None of these seem to convey what my **You Tube video** is for. It is not written instructions, it is a *kind of* step by step guide.

Basically it is a music creation video. I create a complex rhythm part using only a basic modular synthesizer in a mobile app. Showing how it can be utilized for things other than simple synth notes. The video is simply a screen and audio recording showing me creating the part from start to finish. You can then adjust my version to your liking.

The terms "Guide", "Tutorial" and "How-to" don't feel right to me.

Could you suggest a better term?

Comment: I haven't bothered to follow your link, but from what you say here it sounds like what you've put together is a ***demonstration***.

Comment: @fum Why did you put that in a comment?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Demonstration would be good, if there weren't already a similar word in the music biz, *demo tape*.

Comment: Is your primary goal with this recording to entertain (so people can enjoy watching your creative process), or to teach people how to do it themselves, or to give them an introduction to what the equipment and software can be used to make, or as publicity for you to increase your sales of something, or...?  More information would be very helpful.

Comment: What about [brief/exhaustive] "overview" (*a general explanation or description of something*) ?

Comment: @aparente001 That's a good question... I'd say the *primary* goal would be to show people what can be done with that instrument, so they can try it themselves and maybe expand on it. To me, it goes further than that particular software, I'm manipulating the basic parameters of analog-style synthesizers. Modular in this case. It probably would be viewed as entertainment by some viewers. This is my first video of this kind so I am unsure of the actual viewer demographic. Self-promotion is always a factor. But not the *main* purpose of this video.

Comment: Thank you.  *A Video Introduction to the Modular Synthesizer*.  And then you could give it a subtitle.

Answer (score 1):

**Walkthrough** is the term I would use. According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/walkthrough), the relevant definition is:

> a step-by-step demonstration of a procedure or process

Comment: That description would be perfect if it didn't have step-by-step as the main focus.

Comment: @n00dles "it is a kind of step by step guide." That's what you said it was.

Comment: Yeah, *kind of* being the bit I'm having trouble with. *"Walkthrough"* seems more of a *detailed* step by step. I +1'd anyway.